Continuous time semimartingale that is not an Ito-Diffusion
Let $X_t$ be a continuous semimartingale. Does there exist $\mu, \sigma$ such that,
$d X_t = \mu(X_t, t) dt + \sigma(X_t, t) dW$
If $X_t$ was only a semimartingale, then the answer is no, because I can choose $X_t$ to be a pure jump process. By enforcing continuity, I disallow this.
I think this is not enough though, because an Ito diffusion must be Feller continuous. If this is correct, is there an example of a continuous semimartingale that is not an Ito diffusion?
If $X_t$ is taken to be a Feller continuous semimartingale, is it now the case $X_t$ is an Ito diffusion? If no, then what other assumption is needed?

Let $(B_t)$ be a standard Brownian motion started at $0$. Define $X_t:=|B_t|$,
$$
{\rm sgn}(x) :=\cases{1,&$x>0$,\cr 0,&$x=0$,\cr -1,&$x<0$,\cr} 
$$
and $W_t:=\int_0^t{\rm sgn}(B_s)\,dB_s$. Then
$$
X_t=L_t+ W_t,
$$
in which $t\mapsto L_t$ is non-decreasing and continuous, but singular in the sense that ${d\over dt}L_t=0$ for a.e. $t>0$, almost surely. ($(L_t)$ is the local time of $X$ in state $0$.) The process $(X_t)$ is a continuous semimartingale in the filtration of $(B_t)$; its martingale part is $(W_t)$, but its finite variation part $L_t$ is not absolutely continuous as it would be for an Ito process.
The process  $(X_t)$ is a presentation of Reflecting Brownian Motion on $[0,\infty)$; as such it is a (strong) Markov process, even a Feller process.

Thank you, both your and @user6247850 's answers were very informative, but this one was more in the spirit of what I was looking for. Is this example covered in a textbook anywhere?

It will be in any text that discusses the difference between strong and weak solutions of SDEs. For example, in section 5.3 of Oksendal's book Stochastic
Differential Equations.

Any process satisfying $dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t$ must be a Markov process, so you can take $X$ to be your favorite non-Markov continuous semimartingale.  For example, $X_t = \int_0^t B_s ds$ where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion works because $dX_t = B_t dt$ and $B_t \ne \mu(X_t,t)$ for any function $\mu$.

This is interesting if we are forced to live in 1 dimension, but otherwise I can define the process $X_t = (X^1_t , X^2_t)$  with $\mu(X) = (X_2, 0)$ and $\sigma(X) = (0 , 0 ;0 ,1) $ such that $dX = \mu(X)dt + \sigma(X) dW$ for a Brownian motion $W_t = (W^1_t, W^2_t)$.
Which implies $X^2_t = W^2_t$, and $dX^1_t = W^2_t dt$

@TheoDiamantakis Sure, there exist Markov processes closely related to this $X$, but that doesn't change the fact that this process doesn't satisfy $dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t$ for any functions $\mu, \sigma$.

But there are such $\mu$, $\sigma$ -unless you arbitrarily try and force a 2d process into 1 dimension.  Certainly it is a valid counterexample, but it doesn't elucidate whether there is a huge difference between the set of semimartingales and diffusions. Suppose I added Markovian to the conditions, in this case, is a Markovian continuous semimartingale now a diffusion?
